# Turn on and off drag drop table rows jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the following code to drag html table rows up or down and it works pretty well.

```
     $("#positionTable tbody").sortable({
        appendTo: "parent",
        helper: "clone",
        update: function (e, ui) {

            $('#positionTable tr').each(function (event, ui) {
                    var id= ui.id;
                    alert(id);  
            })
      }

    }).disableSelection();
```

What I want to do is to toggle the function on and off based upon an edit button.  I only want the sorting when in edit mode.

Thanks

Comment: do you have a demo of this ?

Comment: I used this demo as a starting point http://jsfiddle.net/mcoomey/Vn5SZ/1/

Comment: also if you are using the jquery ui sortable widget, it looks like there is an option for you to disable it, here is a link with info https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-disabled

Comment: $("#positionTable tbody").sortable("disable"); and    $("#positionTable tbody").sortable("enable");  works.  Thanks